# Graph API and Insights returning different number of fans

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am querying the number of fans of a page using two different methods, graph and insights but they are returning two different numbers.

My call to the graph API is:
https://graph.facebook.com/page_name

and my Insights call is:
https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/insights/page_fans

In almost every page I've tested the number of fans from Insights is lower than the number of likes from the graph API.  The number that the Graph API is giving me is the same as the fan count on the actual Facebook page.  Is there a difference between Likes and Fans in these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the FB Insights developer page there is a FAQ that explains this discrepancy:

"**Why does the count next to my Like Button not match what I see in Insights?**

The count next to the Like Button represents the sum of Like Button clicks, News Feed likes, News Feed comments, and shares on Facebook."

[Facebook Insights](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/)

Answer (score 0):

A bit old thread but interesting for all nowadays.

If these two values are not the same, it's because it concerns local page:
- The fan count will be equals to the total likes of the page
- The insights fan count will be equals to the total likes of the local page

E.g.

- page1   graph fan_count: 500
- page1FR graph fan_count: 500
- page1FR insight fan_count: 100
- page1EN insight fan_count: 400

(here there are only two localized pages).